# Ejecucion de un query segun timeout

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Muy buenas amigos queria saber si me pueden ayudar con una idea para solucionar una cuestion.

Quisiera calcular los intereses que un cliente tiene cada cierta cantidad de tiempo (24 hrs por ejemplo).

Tengo la idea de hacer un Timer Out Global, y cuando el reloj llegue a 0, hacer un UPDATE a todos los clientes que se encuentran en mi base de datos.

```
CREATE TABLE ahorro(
ahorro_id int not null PRIMARY key AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id int not null,
user_uid int not null,
capital_real float(11,2) not null,
monto float(11,2) not null,
interes_recibidos float(11,2) not null,
capital_total float(11,2) not null,
hist_date datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

en donde:

monto: Es la cantidad que el cliente va a ingresar.

capital_real: Es la sumatoria de los montos que el usuario ha ingresado.

interes_recibidos: Es (capital_real*15*1/36000).

capital_total:  Es la sumatoria (capital_real+interes_recibidos).

Mi duda es si puedo ejecutar todo en determinada cantidad de tiempo. y si se puede, hay forma de actualizar las columnas(capital_real, interes_recibidos, capital_total)  al mismo tiempo.

Saludos, gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer, y creo que sería lo mas correcto es crear una tarea programada en tu  base de datos. De este modo puedes especificar una acción a realizar tras haber transcurrido un determinado tiempo. Deberías seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Primero tenemos que asegurarnos de que tenemos el scheduler arrancado esto lo vemos con un: `mysql> SHOW processlist;`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No está arrancado, para esto tenemos que modificar un parámetro de **my.cnf** en la seccion mysqld: `event-scheduler=ON`. Reiniciamos mysql y podemos verificar que:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora creamos el evento, siguiendo la sintaxis:

```
CREATE
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
EVENT
[IF NOT EXISTS]
event_name
ON SCHEDULE schedule
[ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE]
[ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
[COMMENT 'comment']
DO event_body;
schedule:
AT timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...
| EVERY interval
[STARTS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]
[ENDS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]
interval:
quantity {YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE |
WEEK | SECOND | YEAR_MONTH | DAY_HOUR | DAY_MINUTE |
DAY_SECOND | HOUR_MINUTE | HOUR_SECOND | MINUTE_SECOND}
```

Para nuestro caso:

```
CREATE event evento_intereses ON schedule every 24 hour do (Aquí van las acciones que necesites realizar, ya sea un update, llamar a un sp, etc.);
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Wow excelente comentario amigo, voy a probar este metodo <3 Fran Islas Saludos!
Gracias por tu tiempo amigo.

Comment: Fran Islas saludos fijate que hice una prueba con otra tabla a ver si me funcionaba pero en la consulta me tira un error y no se porque.
es un #1064 ERROR en la linea 6 despues de END

Comment: DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE EVENT calcular_intereses

ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
 BEGIN 
  UPDATE prueba1 set interes= (capital_real*15*1/36000)
 END //

DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

Para este tipo de soluciones recomiendo utilizar Crontab o utilizar un procedimiento en la base de datos que actualice los campos que necesitas.

En servidor:

Si tienes acceso al servidor lo mejor seria hacer un Script.php que realice lo siguiente:

1. Conectarse a base de datos
2. Solicitar datos y aplicar nuevo calculo
3. Actualizar cambios

Luego de hacer el Script.php tienes que dar permisos de ejecución con el comando 'chmod', por ejemplo:

```
chmod a+x script.php
```

Y luego agregar el Script a tu servidor con 'crontab', para eso escribes en la terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

Y al final del documento agregas el temporizador (username es el nombre de usuario del servidor):

```
5 3 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/username/script.php
```

La linea anterior ejecutara el script a las 3:05 AM. Este ejemplo tiene el tiempo definidos, luego el interprete y después la ruta del script a ejecutar.

Como dato, con esta web puedes revisar la configuración de tu Cron: https://crontab.guru/

Y si quieres encontrar la ruta de tu interprete en PHP puedes usar el siguiente comando en tu terminal:

```
which php
```

Si piensa hacer un temporizador en Javascript en la vista pienso que puede ser arriesgado. Y si no tienes acceso al servidor para hacer un cron entonces un procedimiento en base de dato puede ser lo más viable.

Ahora si usas Node.js entonces puedes hacer un script en Javascript y usar esta Biblioteca para el Crontab: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron